# How to tell pair of RAID1 drives is successfully mirroring?

Tags: server, hard-drive, raid

This is not an urgent problem, but I would like to know if I am currently making use of both of my hard drives (and/or if I can fix that).

Essentially, I purchased [this computer without an OS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079VRBPG4) and I have successfully installed Ubuntu Server on it.

The computer comes with **2** 3TB hard drives.

My understanding is that I can either have a RAID0 configuration to have 6 TB of storage space, or a RAID1 configuration where 1 3 TB drive mirrors the other 3 TB drive.

Given that I have started to run analysis on the server, I am OK with mirroring the hard drive (RAID1).

However, I don't think I have successfully done that.  For example, if I check my `/proc/mdstat` file, this is what it says:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md126 : active raid1 sda[1] sdb[0]
      2930264064 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/2] [UU]

md127 : inactive sda[1](S) sdb[0](S)
      5040 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

Likewise, this how those drives are recognized using `lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT`

```
NAME         SIZE FSTYPE          TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda          2.7T isw_raid_member disk
└─md126      2.7T                 raid1
  ├─md126p1  512M vfat            md    /boot/efi
  └─md126p2  2.7T ext4            md    /
sdb          2.7T isw_raid_member disk
└─md126      2.7T                 raid1
  ├─md126p1  512M vfat            md    /boot/efi
  └─md126p2  2.7T ext4            md    /
sr0         1024M                 rom
```

This is the available space that I have using `df`:

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev             16370772         0   16370772   0% /dev
tmpfs             3280440       940    3279500   1% /run
/dev/md126p2   2882700496 223265236 2512931992   9% /
tmpfs            16402180         0   16402180   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16402180         0   16402180   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md126p1       523248      6152     517096   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs             3280436         0    3280436   0% /run/user/1000
```

**So, my questions are as follows:**

1. Am I actually mirroring my hard drive with a RAID1 configuration?
   If so, how can I recover my hard drive is something goes wrong?

   From the `/proc/mdstat` file, it looks like there is some sort of the link between the drives (since `md126` is listed with `super external:/md127/0`, on the 2nd line)
2. If both hard drives are not currently being used (for RAID1 mirroring), what do I need to change?  Can I start mirroring my first hard drive without erasing everything currently on the first drive?

I converted 2 answers to provide additional information for the question (please see below).

**Comment/Update #1**

If I use the MD administration function `mdadm`, then I can see the following information:

I believe this is for the 1st RAID hardrive:

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md126
/dev/md126:
         Container : /dev/md/imsm0, member 0
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 2930264064 (2794.52 GiB 3000.59 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 2930264064 (2794.52 GiB 3000.59 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2

             State : active
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync


              UUID : xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       1       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       0       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md126p1
/dev/md126p1:
         Container : /dev/md/imsm0, member 0
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 524288 (512.00 MiB 536.87 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 18446744073709551615
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2

             State : active
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync


              UUID : xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       1       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       0       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb

$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md126p2
/dev/md126p2:
         Container : /dev/md/imsm0, member 0
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 2929737728 (2794.02 GiB 3000.05 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 2930264064 (2794.52 GiB 3000.59 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2

             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync


              UUID : xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       1       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       0       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
```

and I believe this is for the 2nd RAID harddrive:

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : imsm
        Raid Level : container
     Total Devices : 2

   Working Devices : 2


              UUID : xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx
     Member Arrays : /dev/md/Volume1

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8        0        -        /dev/sda
       -       8       16        -        /dev/sdb
```

Otherwise, I guess the RAID1 configuration is set up (and that is what `md126p1` and `md126p2` stand for)?

For example, it does say `Raid Level : raid1` for the 1st drive, although I wonder why it doesn't say that for the 2nd drive

For posting on-line, I set the UUIDs to be "xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx", but I otherwise have provided the exact output.

There are also 4 other files where I can look up additional information, including the "Volume1" that I believe refers to the 2nd drive?

```
$ ls /dev/md/
imsm0      Volume1    Volume1p1  Volume1p2
~$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md/Volume1
/dev/md/Volume1:
         Container : /dev/md/imsm0, member 0
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 2930264064 (2794.52 GiB 3000.59 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 2930264064 (2794.52 GiB 3000.59 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2

             State : active
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync


              UUID : xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       1       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       0       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
```

There are also `mdadm --create`, `mdadm --grow`, and `mdadm --incremental` functions.

FYI, I decided to add these notes after taking this class: https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-ubuntu-linux-server-administration-course/

**Comment/Update #2**

**1)** You can see the following information with `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 5860526079 5859475456  2.7T Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624 5860526079 5859475456  2.7T Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/md126: 2.7 TiB, 3000590401536 bytes, 5860528128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx

Device         Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/md126p1    2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/md126p2 1050624 5860526079 5859475456  2.7T Linux filesystem
```

Since this already says that /dev/sdb is a Linux file system, I think that part is OK.

For posting on-line, I set the UUIDs to be "xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx", but I otherwise have provided the exact output.

**2)** While I want to be cautious, I think the next step involves the command `mkfs.ext4`. However, I want to be careful and learn more before I do something that may (or may not) affect my current file system.

If I try to use the `mount` command, then this is what I currently see:

```
$:/mnt$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/test1
mount: /mnt/test1: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist.
$:/mnt$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/test1
mount: /mnt/test1: special device /dev/sda2 does not exist.
$:/mnt$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/test1
mount: /mnt/test1: /dev/sdb1 already mounted or mount point busy.
$:/mnt$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/test1
mount: /mnt/test1: /dev/sdb2 already mounted or mount point busy.
```

FYI, I previously learned about `fdisk`, but I didn't see that in the earlier notes.  Otherwise, I added new notes from the following class(es):

https://www.linkedin.com/learning/building-an-ubuntu-home-server/add-storage-with-a-local-disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I am still not sure how to test data recovery, I think my question contained the answer to confirm that I had set up RAID1:

Likewise, this how those drives are recognized using `lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT`

```
NAME         SIZE FSTYPE          TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda          2.7T isw_raid_member disk
└─md126      2.7T                 raid1
  ├─md126p1  512M vfat            md    /boot/efi
  └─md126p2  2.7T ext4            md    /
sdb          2.7T isw_raid_member disk
└─md126      2.7T                 raid1
  ├─md126p1  512M vfat            md    /boot/efi
  └─md126p2  2.7T ext4            md    /
sr0         1024M                 rom
```

If there was not a raid configuration, then I don't think it should have said "raid1" above for both hard drives (sda and sdb).